# What's the best way to do classical forms over data using Node.js?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, node.js, web-applications, sails.js

I am in the need of creating a classical forms-over-data application using Node.js, including server-side rendering. I know that this is definitely not a good use case for Node.js for various reasons, nevertheless, I have to do it.

*So let's please avoid discussion whether this is meaningful, or similar things - just take it as given.*

Now I wonder what's the best way to fulfill this task. Of course, I could create such an app completely manually, using Express and MongoDB, and hand-writing routes and controllers, and stuff like this. It's basically not a big deal, but this compares quite bad to solutions such as ASP.NET MVC (which I'd prefer for this kind of task, to be true).

Now I found out about Sails.js, which is a heavily Rails-inspired MVC framework for Node.js, and which looks quite good. But before I now start experimenting in more depth with Sails.js, I wanted to ask what other options might be viable?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Be more specific as to what you are trying to do.  As you have seen, there are many options...

Answer (score 0):

If you have ruby on rails 2.x background then check this out http://compoundjs.com/
rails 3.x check this http://tower.github.io/ or sails.js or geddyjs